# Can we add xml output to outputstream or buffer instead of saving it to particular destination

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the code to place xml file to particular destination .

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public XmlDataDocument GetList(string keyword1, string streetname, string lat, string lng, string radius)
{

  XmlDataDocument xmlDoc=  CreateXML( keyword1,streetname,lat,lng,radius);
  xmlDoc.Save(@"D:\blockseek7-9-2010\Block3.xml");
         return xmlDoc;
    // can i save it to outputstream or buffer 
}
```

Comment: What is the reason you r saving it to a file? If its for temporary purposes then you can keep files in temp directory.

Answer (score 2):

the first overload of xmlDoc.Save takes a stream

Comment: I have a ajax call to that webservice ,if the output is saved to particular destination that output will be referenced by my clientside ajax call .Its good for the first time if i refer D:\blockseek7-9-2010\Block3.xml but during second iteration the ajax call refers to previous xml file itself